# Extract specific fields from xml file

Tags: xml, go

I have an XML file. I need to extract specific fields from that XML file and store in the mongo. How to extract only name field user from below XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
  <user type="admin">
    <name>Elliot</name>
    <social>
      <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
    </social>
  </user>
  <user type="reader">
    <name>Fraser</name>
    <social>
      <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
    </social>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General XML parser in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859030/general-xml-parser-in-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
  <user type="admin">
    <name>Elliot</name>
    <social>
      <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
    </social>
  </user>
  <user type="reader">
    <name>Fraser</name>
    <social>
      <facebook>https://facebook.com</facebook>
    </social>
  </user>
</users>
`

type Users struct {
    Users []*User `xml:"user"`
}

type User struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    var users Users
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &users); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, user := range users.Users {
        fmt.Println(user.Name)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/m65Eio6xskS

Comment: If I have a large xml file. Do I need to define the entire structure as models in GO?

Comment: @Chinna: No. You only need to define those that you are interested in extracting.

Comment: If I want to read the **lang**, **di**, **a** and **b** fields(tags) from below xml code.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/XMLSchema-instance">
    <lang code="Eng" />
    <dir>
        <par>
            <di root="2337" expansion="86756" />
            <hca>
                <name>
                    <a>1234</a>
                    <a>12</a>
                    <b>2337</b>
                </name>
            </hca>
        </par>
    </dir>
</Person>`

Comment: we can create the structs for the simple xml file. but if we have the complex one like above. Do you have any suggestions on this?